# How to automatically detect the correct circles in an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

[image]

I have an image like above and I want to detect the circle like in the below image in blue
[image]

However, when I do, [image]
the red circle is detected.
[image]
How would I automatically detect blue circle instead of the red? (without going through every single circular contour)

Comment: you could try to threshold the blue color and afterwards use RANSAC circle detection (search on SO, I'voe posted several answers with implementations).

Comment: @Micka: haha, I was also tempted to make this joke answer.

Comment: as a real answer: Threshold the bright region (close to white), extract edges and use RANSAC circle detection.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Depending on your goal, maybe a rectangular to polar conversion could be useful...

Comment: My ultimate goal is to change the gauge image to a rectangular image (so that the ticks are aligned like a ruler). I want find the blue circle in order get the center of the gauge, because I need to know the center to correctly change to rectangular image, or else the image gets distorted.

Answer (score 1):

This code below will give you multiple circles when you pass the image. Also, it will give you the count. You can edit it out later on.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,27,3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
count = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ratio = w/h
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    if ratio > .85 and ratio < 1.20 and area > 50 and area < 120 and r < 7:
        cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (36, 255, 12), -1)
        count += 1

print('Count: {}'.format(count))

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```